# Deprecated Grails Plugins

Tags: grails, plugins, deprecated

I'm doing an upgrade from Grails 2.2.1 to 2.3.4 and upgrading the plugins as I go as well. When I compile I get a message that states:

```
 NOTE: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
 NOTE: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details
```

I tried recompiling with the flag:

```
 grails compile -Xlint:deprecation
```

The application doesn't relinquish anymore details about the deprecated plugin. I've searched online and don't see any documentation for the "-Xlint:deprecation" flag. I know I could just take off a plugin and compile to find the one its referring to, but I'd like to know how to use this "-Xlint:deprecation" for future use and ease.

Comment: -Xlint:deprecation is a java compiler flag.

Comment: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html Search for "java_opts"

Comment: I tried to specify the environment variable GRAILS_OPTS="-Xlint:deprecation" in Windows by going to system properties -> advanced -> environment variables and creating the GRAIL_OPTS variable and populating it with "-Xlint:deprecation" when I run a grails command it comes back: "unrecognized option: -Xlint:deprecation Could not create the java virtual machine."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Grails 2.4.0, if you specify

```
-Xlint:deprecation
```

as a command-line option, Grails ignores this option and places it in it's [DefaultCommandLine's undeclaredOptions HashMap](https://github.com/brippe/grails-core/blob/master/grails-bootstrap/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/cli/parsing/DefaultCommandLine.java#L35). Grails explicitly sets the compilerargs for javac to

```
-Xlint:-options
```

This sets ["no further warnings about command line options are generated from this point on"](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/langtools/file/1ff9d5118aae/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/javac/main/JavaCompiler.java#l847).

You can see this in the Grails code on line 285 in the [GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/6032036d1bc9d395ad7d9ebda6537dce00ba1baa/grails-project-api/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/project/compiler/GrailsProjectCompiler.groovy#L285)

This is why setting JAVA_OPTS="-Xlint:-deprecation" or GRAILS_OPTS doesn't work. See the unresolved Jira issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7670?jql=project%20%3D%20GRAILS%20AND%20text%20~%20javac.